# How do I keep a responsive UI while processing large amounts of data?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I am creating winform to process (convert txt files to tiff) large amount of files. I put all the code behind a button (btnProcess). Is this a good idea? It works but I noticed when I go away from the winform and come back to this I see blank window until the process is complete. I heard about background worker. what is the purpose of background worker?

Comment: try to make your question as descriptive as possible to assist other users facing similar problems and also to attract the best answers possible. "winform question" is not likely to achieve either goal.

Comment: Good suggestion. I like the new title, it makes more sense. I just didnt know those fancy words or technical lingo.

Answer (score 9):

What you need here is multi-threading. That means that two (or more) threads of code would run in parallel. One of them would be the UI thread, the one responsible for drawing the window. In your case you are running your code in the UI thread and thus blocking the UI rendering while your code is running.

The purpose of the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) is to start an operation on a new thread and is what you need.

Comment: Also, since you are dealing with a large amount of files, you might want to consider more than one background threads so that you can process multiple files in parallel

Comment: Absolutely. It is however worth noting that this will mostly benefit multi-core CPUs (most of recent CPUs anyway). This will also be easier to achieve by multi-threading a for loop using something like Parallel Extensions rather than creating X BackgroundWorkers.

Comment: @Raj: you have to be careful when you start talking about File IO. This is the slowest process and multi-threading a bunch of file operations does not guarantee any gains in performance.

Comment: It really depends what the longest operation is, in this particular case: loading (and saving) the file or processing it?

Comment: I tried the background tread but it's too complicated. especially, when i have to get hold of form's controls. i guess i will just use UI tread. I have a subroutine that i was calling from button click. i changed the button click to go to dowork and then calling the subroutine but it's getting messy.

Comment: Then the other response where they suggest to use Application.DoEvents() may be of interest to you. This will let you run the code on the UI thread (then you won't have to dispatch your UI update calls on the UI thread as with the BackgroundWorker), but still won't _completely_ block the UI

Answer (score 3):

[BackgroundWorker class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

> The BackgroundWorker class allows you
>   to run an operation on a separate,
>   dedicated thread. Time-consuming
>   operations like downloads and database
>   transactions can cause your user
>   interface (UI) to seem as though it
>   has stopped responding while they are
>   running. When you want a responsive UI
>   and you are faced with long delays
>   associated with such operations, the
>   BackgroundWorker class provides a
>   convenient solution.

The page I linked above contains **a complete BackgroundWorker example**.

Comment: If you are new to multi-threading paradigm, I suggest you use the background worker, it is an abstraction to multi-thread programming.

Comment: If we are using all the service methods in async, Task. Then it may degrade the performance (in large application) ?

Comment: That is a very broad question. If you run too many tasks in parallel, you will overload the system at some point. However, without more details, it's impossible to tell whether it means 5 tasks or 100.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your application.   If this is a single purpose application that is not extremely long and the only problem is the screen doesn't paint.  Which is what it sounds like to me, just throw an Application.DoEvents into the loop and be done with it.