# VB.Net Multithreading Windows Form

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have written below code. When I click one button 1 window freezes even though I used threading. Button 2 click event starts when button 1 task gets completed. I want to run and start processing as soon as I click on the button. Even when I click on button 1 I can't move windows form... 
I am using Visual Studio 2008

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class MultiThreading

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim i2 As Integer
    Dim thread As System.Threading.Thread
    Dim thread2 As System.Threading.Thread
    Delegate Sub DelegateCountup()
    Delegate Sub DelegateCountup2()

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        thread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf countup)
        thread.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        thread2 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf countup2)
        thread2.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub countup()
        If InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New DelegateCountup(AddressOf countup)
            Me.Invoke(d)
        Else
            Do Until i = 2000
                i = i + 1
                Label1.Text = i
                Me.Refresh()
            Loop
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub countup2()
         If InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New DelegateCountup(AddressOf countup2)
            Me.Invoke(d)
         Else
            Do Until i2 = 1000
                i2 = i2 + 1
                Label2.Text = i2
                Me.Refresh()
            Loop
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You should use Backgrounworker class instead.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the normal threading construct, use the backgroundworker class. That will keep the UI responsive. A similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539369/how-do-i-keep-a-responsive-ui-while-processing-large-amounts-of-data)