# How to stop C# application's UI from becoming unresponsive when downloading large file from the internet

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a C# WPF application. In my code, I download a large file from the internet using WebClient.DownloadFile().

When I do this, the application's UI becomes unresponsive (the app doesn't freeze, if I leave it for long enough it would have downloaded and it goes back to normal).

The code itself is in another script, called from the UI thread. What's the best way to stop the UI from becoming unresponsive?

Comment: The answer is obvious, isn't it? Download the file in a different thread

Comment: By making use of multithreading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I keep a responsive UI while processing large amounts of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539369/how-do-i-keep-a-responsive-ui-while-processing-large-amounts-of-data)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [WebClient.DownloadFileAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144197(v=vs.110).aspx) method to download the file in a worker thread.  The UI thread will stay responsive during this process.

The method documentation explains it nicely:

> This method downloads the resource at the URI specified by in the
>   address parameter. When the download completes successfully, the
>   downloaded file is named fileName on the local computer. The file is
>   downloaded asynchronously using thread resources that are
>   automatically allocated from the thread pool. To receive notification
>   when the file is available, add an event handler to the
>   DownloadFileCompleted event.
>
> This method does not block the calling thread while the resource is
>   being downloaded. To block while waiting for the download to complete,
>   use one of the DownloadFile methods.
>
> You can use the CancelAsync method to cancel asynchronous operations
>   that have not completed.

Answer (score -1):

Use something like this:

```
... //You earlier code
await Task.Run(() => /*your large file downloading code */);
...//Your later code
```

Comment: Task.Run should be reserved for CPU bound work, not IO bound work. Just async/await is what you want.

Comment: @Crowcoder It's a best practice way for wrapping sync code to async, man. Read more about async/await realization here https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/async-in-depth   You'll see that just the same mechanisms are used in .NET async methods.

Comment: I actually have read up on it. That's why I know it is wasteful to run IO bound code in Task.Run. There is no indication that OP is restricted to synchronous code here.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, I know most of examples from this article and "better" approaches for wrapping sync code with async. And my recommendation was like in this article: "Conclusion: do not use Task.Run in the implementation of the method; instead, use Task.Run to call the method."

Comment: @Dmitriy CPU-bound asynchronous functions and IO-bound asynchronous function do not use the same mechanisms. The first is using threads (at least Task.Run does) , whereas the latter doesn't need threads.

Comment: @Crowcoder Hm... Thnxs. You improved my skills. Really, I/O async based on "In synchronous file I/O, a thread starts an I/O operation and immediately enters a wait state until the I/O request has completed. A thread performing asynchronous file I/O sends an I/O request to the kernel by calling an appropriate function. If the request is accepted by the kernel, the calling thread continues processing another job until the kernel signals to the thread that the I/O operation is complete. It then interrupts its current job and processes the data from the I/O operation as necessary."

Comment: @ckuri Thnx you too!

Comment: @Crowcoder Pls, could you give me a link where I could read enough about writing async I/O methods in correct way?

Comment: Basically just read [Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and [Stephen Toub's](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/) blogs. Also, [I have a sample app](https://contrivedexample.com/2017/12/04/configureawait-sometimes-saves-the-day-everytime/) that demonstrates some async behavior that is not directly I/O related but maybe helpful.